# Grouping Node JS Modules similar to Maven groupId

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, maven

I am new to NodeJS coming from a Maven background.

In Maven, there is the concept of groupId and artifactID along with the package name which we want to have when we create a new project.

In NodeJS I see only a module name. There is no groupId as in maven. Also, there is no package. Maybe  packages are not required in NodeJS.

But, still grouping related modules together is a desirable factor. so I feel there should be an equivalent of maven groupId in maven.

But,I  not able to find one so far in Node JS.

Can someone please help me with the right approach to create modules within groups in NodeJS similar to maven groupId and artifactId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with how maven works unfortunately. But you can create packages in the Node environment with `npm`:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Each package (or group of modules, to stay within your vocabulary) has to have a `package.json` describing name, version, included files, scripts, etc. See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json for more details.

These packages are then published into a registry. This can either be the official/default `npm` registry or a private registry hosted by software like Nexus or Artifactory.

I think the equivalent of `groupId` and `artifactId` is `name` in your `package.json` file(s).

Answer (score 0):

**Scoped package** are the maven equivalent: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages . (`@group-id` can be your reverse domain name: `org.company.team`)

```
{
  "name": "@group-id/artifact-id",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```